# (JDA) How do I check for two different event types in the same method?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I know this sounds super simple and dumb but honestly im new to java and am having trouble figuring this out.

I have a class Reactions that checks for a react and a method onGameStart that startups a "game" i made (or will make)

```
@Override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent e) {
    Game start = new Game();
    TextChannel pOneChannel = e.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("player-1",true).get(0);
    TextChannel pTwoChannel = e.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("player-2",true).get(0);
    
    if(e.getTextChannel().getIdLong() == channelID) {
        pOneChannel.sendMessage(playerOne()).queue();
        pTwoChannel.sendMessage(playerTwo()).queue();
    }
    if(e.getTextChannel() == pOneChannel) {
        if(e.getTextChannel() != pTwoChannel)
            printMessage("Waiting for players...", e);
        else
            start.onGameStart();
    }
    else if(e.getTextChannel() == pTwoChannel) {
        if(e.getTextChannel() != pOneChannel)
            printMessage("Waiting for players...", e);
        else
            start.onGameStart();
    }   
}
```

Before, I had the class Game require a MessageReceivedEvent. But of course this would mean I would need that as a parameter in the above class. When adding it to the above class, I can no longer override and it doesnt work.
So then I made my Game class have a method that runs with a MessageReceivedEvent that is just passed in with a null value. But of course this doesnt work, I need a real value. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Also another error I have is that I'd like to check for an emote response in the player 1 and player two channels. When there exists a response in both, start the game. I tried to write that above but it just runs Waiting for players.. every time. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not process multiple Event-Types with one method. It's that simple. The Event Structure calls a generic method (`EventListener#onEvent(GenericEvent e)`) on each individual Event. That includes everything, like receiving a message or a new reaction.

However I assume your Listener extends the `ListenerAdapter`-Class. This class implements some logic that splits all events in seperate methods. These methods are the one you are overriding. These are only provided for Singular Events (although there are some supertypes of events). If you want something to happen on two different event types you have basically two options:

- You use the `GenericEvent` and parse everything yourself (I do not recommend doing this, but it is possible)
- You override all Events you need and call a helper Method as shown below:

```java
@Override
public void onMessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    utilMethod(/*add Args here*/);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    utilMethod(/*add Args here*/);
}

private void utilMethod(/*add Args here*/) {
    // do stuff
}
```

However these methods are still called for every event individually. Assume you and a friend send two messages at the exact same time (theoretically). JDA would still trigger the method two times with information for each message individually. If you want to do a ready check (since I assume you want to do something like that) you have to save the state of your game and update it depending on the messages you receive.

E.g. you could have a class player like this:

```java
public class Player {
    long id; // Represents the Discord ID
    boolean ready = false; // Update this on a message
    // ... some other stuff
}
```

and then update the `Player#ready` field when you receive the event and then check if all players are ready.

Hope this helps you understand the Event-Architecture of JDA a little better :D